# Zend Framework using datatable

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, datatables

I am trying to implementa website using datatable and zend framework to take data from mysql database. Here is my view.phtml

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="shadow-table" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody bgcolor="#E2E4FF">   

        </tbody>
```

controller.php

```
public function getdataAction() {
            $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $shadow = new Admin_Model_Shadow();
        $result = $shadow->listall();
        $this->view->a = $result;
        json_encode($result);
        }
```

and my model.php

```
class Admin_Model_Shadow extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = "users";
    protected $_primary = "user_id";

    public function listall() {
        $db = $this->getDefaultAdapter();
        $query = $db->select()
                ->from('users',array('user_id','name','email');
        return $db->fetchAll($query);
    }

}
```

Now i want to show the `$result` in the view.phtml via datatable. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the short answer, I will try to add some more details if i get the time to do so.

This is a Controller Action i used in a project years ago.

You have to tell in Controller::init() that your datatableAction will need to return JSON instead of a rendered view script.

```
/**
 * Initialise Controller
 *
 * @return void 
 */
public function init() {
    /* 
     * Set Request/Response Context (HTML,XML,JSON) for Ajax Request
     * Add ?format=json to URL e.g. http://test.com/test?format=json
     */
    $this->_helper  ->contextSwitch()
                     //add context for datatablesAction() Response is JSON
                    ->addActionContext('datatable', 'json')
                    ->initContext();

    parent::init();
}
```

This is my Action currently in use, if i get the time i will modify it to fit your variable names.

```
/**
 * Get evn records via AJAX call converted to jquery datatable format
 * 
 * @link http://www.datatables.net/
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function datatableAction() {
    /* @var $request Zend_Controller_Request_Http */
    $request    = $this->getRequest();
    /* @var $cache Zend_Session_Namespace */
    $cache      = new Zend_Session_Namespace("cache");

    $array      = $cache->{$module};
    $selected   = $array["selected"];

    /* @var $cdrFactory Evn_Model_RecordsFactory */
    $cdrFactory = new Evn_Model_RecordsFactory();

    //set request object attributes via magic setter from caches selection array
    $cdrFactory->account     = $selected["account"];
    $cdrFactory->direction   = $selected["direction"];
    $cdrFactory->date_start  = $selected["date_start"];
    $cdrFactory->date_end    = $selected["date_end"];

    //get sEcho from Request Object (default 1)
    $page = $request->getParam("sEcho", 1);
    $page = ($page<1) ? 1 : $page;
    //set view variable (auto json format via contextswitch)
    $this->view->sEcho = $page;

    //calculate limit start
    $from   = ($page>1) ? (($page-1) * $selected["entries"]) : 0;
    //calculate limit end
    $end    = ($from + $selected["entries"])-1;

    //set records limit start
    $cdrFactory->limit_begin = $from;
    //set records limit end
    $cdrFactory->limit_end   = $end;

    //request records
    $records    = $cdrFactory->fetch();
    //get size of retrieved records
    $total      = $cdrFactory->getSize();
    //set view variable (auto json format via contextswitch)
    $this->view->iTotalRecords = $total;
    $this->view->iTotalDisplayRecords = $total-(($end-$from)+1);

    //set view variable (auto json format via contextswitch)
    $this->view->sColumns = "call_start,a_partynumber,b_partynumber,seconds,direction,price_complete,price_minute,price_call";
    //create array in datatables format
    $aaData     = array();
    foreach($records as $record) {
        //get plain array 0-x
        $aaData[] = array_values($record);
    }
    //set view variable (auto json format via contextswitch)
    $this->view->aaData = $aaData;
}
```

Take a look at https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side for more Infors about which json parameters your action can or needs to return.

Just add the vars as $this->view->[varname], the JSON Context switch will handle output and headers automatically.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your response!! But i am so new to this, can you just give me an simple example that similar to my code.